EPIPE Error while running frontend code in local machine
I am getting this error while running the frontend application in my local machine, i am using default port:4200.
I have looked upon the internet for the solutions, and tried few of the mas well, I tried updating the packages version. Also tried increasing the memory given to WSL, as i am using WSL. But nothing came to help.
Looking forward to some guidance as this is causing a lot of delay in my work.
Error: write EPIPE
    at target._send (node:internal/child_process:879:20)
    at target.send (node:internal/child_process:752:19)
    at /home/abhinav/Projects/App-Frontend/altius-nx/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/rpc/expose-rpc.js:27:31
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at sendMessage (/home/abhinav/Projects/App-Frontend/altius-nx/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/rpc/expose-rpc.js:19:38)
    at /home/abhinav/Projects/App-Frontend/altius-nx/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/rpc/expose-rpc.js:60:27
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/abhinav/Projects/App-Frontend/altius-nx/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/rpc/expose-rpc.js:5:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errno: -32,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}


please share the code that you've tried

What framework is the frontend application?

we are using react for frontend.

please share the code that you've tried

i can share the code as it belongs to my organization. i could help you with other information that you require for understanding the issue better.
